# Complex inequality $\left|\dfrac{a-b}{1-\overline{a}b}\right|<1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that if $a,b$ are complex numbers such that $|a|<1$ and $ |b|<1$, then $$\left|\dfrac{a-b}{1-\overline{a}b}\right|<1.$$

So I assume $a=p+qi$ and $b=r+si$. Then $a-b=(p-r)+(q-s)i$ and $1-\overline{a}b=(1-pr-qs)-(ps-qr)i$. The inequality turns into $(p-r)^2+(q-s)^2<(1-pr-qs)^2+(ps-qr)^2$, given the condition $p^2+q^2<1, r^2+s^2<1$. How can I continue from here?

Comment: Compute $\lvert 1 - \overline{a}b\rvert^2 - \lvert a-b\rvert^2$. That is much easier.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378074/small-inequality-on-unit-open-disc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with absolute values, most of the time it is much simpler to work with the squares of absolute values, so one should see whether that helps. In this case, we have

$$\begin{gather}
\left\lvert \frac{a-b}{1-\overline{a}b}\right\rvert < 1\\
\iff \left\lvert \frac{a-b}{1-\overline{a}b}\right\rvert^2 < 1\\
\iff \lvert a-b\rvert^2 < \lvert 1 -\overline{a}b\rvert^2\\
\iff 0 < \lvert 1-\overline{a}b\rvert^2 - \lvert a-b\rvert^2\\
\iff 0 < 1 - \overline{a}b - a\overline{b} + \lvert ab\rvert^2 - (\lvert a\rvert^2 - \overline{a}b - a\overline{b} + \lvert b\rvert^2)\\
\iff 0 < (1 - \lvert a\rvert^2)(1 - \lvert b\rvert^2).
\end{gather}$$